# upload image with other form values using along via REST api with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a project which requires uploading of images and whiles uploading I want to send some values as well to the API. I'm currently running a test with postman, the image upload works fine but I'm finding it hard to grab the values sent alongside

[image]

```
    public function newUpload($profileId, Request $request)
    {
    
        try {
    
            if (!$request->hasFile('image')) {
                return response()->json(['upload_file_not_found'], 400);
            }
            $file = $request->file('image');
            if (!$file->isValid()) {
                return response()->json(['invalid_file_upload'], 400);
            }
            $path = public_path() . '/uploads';
            $defaultDateTime = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $rename = "_test" . rand(0, 1000000000) . $profileId . $defaultDateTime . '.' . 
            $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $file->move($path, $rename);
    
     
    
                $workDays = $request->payload->get('workDays');
    
                if ($workDays) {
                    foreach ($workDays as $day) {
                         $data[] = [
                            'profile_id' => $profileId,
                            'name' => $day['name'],
                            'vdate' => $request->payload->tDateTime,
                        ];
                    }
    
                    DB::table('workDays')->insert($data);
                }
            
        } catch (Exception $e) {
    
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to access the `workDays` element you are trying to access a JSON string not a JSON object.

You can get around this by getting the payload from the `Request` object and then `json_decode` the string.

```php
$payload = json_decode($request->payload, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

if ($payload['workDays']) {
    foreach ($payload['workDays'] as $day) {
        $data[] = [
            'profile_id' => $profileId,
            'name' => $day['name'],
            'vdate' => $payload['tDateTime'],
        ];
    }
}
```